# Data transposition and concatenation, how to follow inner join condition?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, group-concat

I've a number of tables that are related between them with a foreign and primary key (basic) system.

I want to concat (comma separated) the values of the last "in-depth" table, respecting to some conditions.

Because it's hard to explain, I've made a draw that, I think, it's pretty explicit:
[image]

Larger image can be found here: http://tinypic.com/r/2ngdaah/6

Note: **tableE** is already created with the column name corresponding to the names presented in **tableD**

Thank you!

### EDITED (fiddle):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f28c8/1/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a query but im not certain is correct. The reason is that the conditions you described used the symbol <= (less than or equal) and it appears to be just = (equal) because of the results below them.

However, Try this:

```
select * 
    from (select id, 
                   name,
                   max(case when e.tableD_id = 1 then  e.agg_values else null end) alpha,
                   max(case when e.tableD_id = 2 then e.agg_values else null end) beta,
                   max(case when e.tableD_id = 3 then e.agg_values else null end) gamma
            from tableA a, 
                (select b.tableA_id, 
                       b.tableD_id, 
                       group_concat(cast(c.value as char) order by c.id asc) agg_values
                  from tableB b,
                       tableC c
                 where c.tableB_id = b.id
                 group by b.tableD_id,b.tableA_id
                 having count(*) >= 3) e
              where a.id = e.tableA_id
              group by id, name
          ) n
          where n.alpha is not null 
            and n.beta is not null 
            and n.gamma is not null
```

**EDIT:**

Modified the query to support the conditions with >= instead of <=.

SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f28c8/1/0

SQLFIDDLE, first condition only: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f28c8/4

Comment: My post is now edited! I'll check your answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: You created the value column as int, it should be double, if you select the tableC (select * from tableC), you'll see that the value column is always 0.

Comment: could you please change it again. sorry, i suppose i messed up your change

Comment: If I just want condition 1 to be true (forget condition 2 or 3), how can I do it? If I just want condition 2 to be true (forget condition 1 or 3), how can I do it?